# extended and basic address box

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am having a user control in my web application. it is to input the communication address.

2 modes are there to input the address: `extended and basic`.

In `extended`, we enter address1, address2, address3, city, state, zip and country in different controls and in  the `basic mode` we enter all the above details in a simple multiline text box.

A toggle button is used to switch between these modes.

It works if i toggle from extended to basic, because it is simple to add all the non empty textboxes with a `vbcrlf` and display it in a multi line text box.

My problem is when we switch from basic to extended. I want to know if there are empty lines or not.
I would be still better if you could provide me with an existing user control with same functionality.

Thanks.

===================================

```
Extended Mode - I enter every thing individually in different textboxes.

+-------------+
|Address 1    |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
|Address 3    |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
|State        |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
|Country      |
+-------------+

          Toggle    


Present scenario - The array

array(0) = "Address1"
array(1) = ""
array(2) = "Address2"
array(3) = ""
array(4) = "State"
array(5) = ""
array(6) = "Country"


I click on the Toggle and switch to Basic mode. Here I am displaying all the address lines which are not empty in a long text box with multiline = True.

+-------------+
|Address1     |
|Address3     |
|State        |
|Country      |
|             |
+-------------+

    Toggle

Now, i will edit the address and delete the Address3 which is on the line 2.

+-------------+
|Address1     |
|State        |
|Country      |
|             |
+-------------+

    Toggle

Now when i click on the toggle, i need to see the textboxes in the extended mode are having the correct values.

+-------------+
|Address 1    |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
|State        |
+-------------+
|             |
+-------------+
|Country      |
+-------------+

          Toggle    

I think, it is clear. i need to go by line by line only as i can enter the same text in two lines.

for example
City - New York.
State - New York.

in the above case, i need to identify which new york (City / State) is deleted / modified.

Thanks.
-=====================
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to your edited question, i've created a UserControl that should work for you. Of course you have to change the layout to your requirement:

**ascx**:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MultiFieldTextbox.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.MultiFieldTextbox" %>
<asp:Panel ID="PnlBasic" Visible="false" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtFields" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" Width="200" Height="200"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="PnlExtended" Visible="true" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAddress1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAddress2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAddress3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtState" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtZip" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="BtnSwitchMode" runat="server" Text="switch mode" />
```

**ascx-codebehind**:

```
Public Class MultiFieldTextbox
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Enum ViewMode As Int32
        Basic
        Extended
    End Enum

    Public Property Mode As ViewMode
        Get
            If Me.PnlBasic.Visible Then
                Return MultiFieldTextbox.ViewMode.Basic
            Else
                Return MultiFieldTextbox.ViewMode.Extended
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ViewMode)
            Me.PnlBasic.Visible = value = ViewMode.Basic
            Me.PnlExtended.Visible = value = ViewMode.Extended
            InitNewMode(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Addr1 As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtAddress1.Text.Trim
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtAddress1.Text = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Addr2 As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtAddress2.Text.Trim
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtAddress2.Text = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Addr3 As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtAddress3.Text.Trim
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtAddress3.Text = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property City As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtCity.Text.Trim
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtCity.Text = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property State As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtState.Text.Trim
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtState.Text = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Zip As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtZip.Text.Trim
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtZip.Text = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Country As String
        Get
            Return Me.TxtCountry.Text.Trim
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.TxtCountry.Text = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property FieldInfos As Dictionary(Of String, FieldInfo)
        Get
            If ViewState("FieldInfos") Is Nothing Then
                ViewState("FieldInfos") = New Dictionary(Of String, FieldInfo)
            End If
            Return DirectCast(ViewState("FieldInfos"), Dictionary(Of String, FieldInfo))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of String, FieldInfo))
            ViewState("FieldInfos") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub InitNewMode(ByVal newMode As ViewMode)
        Select Case newMode
            Case ViewMode.Basic
                Dim builder As New Text.StringBuilder
                Dim lineNumber As Int32 = 0
                Dim key = "Addr1"
                Dim field = Me.Addr1
                FieldInfos = New Dictionary(Of String, FieldInfo)

                lineNumber += 1
                If field.Length <> 0 Then builder.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", field, ControlChars.NewLine))
                FieldInfos.Add(key, New FieldInfo(lineNumber, key, field))
                key = "Addr2"
                field = Me.Addr2
                lineNumber += 1
                If field.Length <> 0 Then builder.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", field, ControlChars.NewLine))
                FieldInfos.Add(key, New FieldInfo(lineNumber, key, field))
                key = "Addr3"
                field = Me.Addr3
                lineNumber += 1
                If field.Length <> 0 Then builder.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", field, ControlChars.NewLine))
                FieldInfos.Add(key, New FieldInfo(lineNumber, key, field))
                key = "City"
                field = Me.City
                lineNumber += 1
                If field.Length <> 0 Then builder.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", field, ControlChars.NewLine))
                FieldInfos.Add(key, New FieldInfo(lineNumber, key, field))
                key = "State"
                field = Me.State
                lineNumber += 1
                If field.Length <> 0 Then builder.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", field, ControlChars.NewLine))
                FieldInfos.Add(key, New FieldInfo(lineNumber, key, field))
                key = "Zip"
                field = Me.Zip
                lineNumber += 1
                If field.Length <> 0 Then builder.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", field, ControlChars.NewLine))
                FieldInfos.Add(key, New FieldInfo(lineNumber, key, field))
                key = "Country"
                field = Me.Country
                lineNumber += 1
                If field.Length <> 0 Then builder.Append(String.Format("{0}{1}", field, ControlChars.NewLine))
                FieldInfos.Add(key, New FieldInfo(lineNumber, key, field))

                If builder.Length <> 0 Then builder.Length -= ControlChars.NewLine.Length
                Me.TxtFields.Text = builder.ToString
            Case ViewMode.Extended
                Dim lineNumber As Int32 = 0
                Dim allLines = Me.TxtFields.Text.Split(New String() {ControlChars.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                For Each line In allLines
                    lineNumber += 1
                    ' set value via old line number '
                    Dim q = From field In Me.FieldInfos
                                Where field.Value.Line = lineNumber
                                Select field
                    If q.Any Then
                        Me.FieldInfos(q.First.Key).Value = line
                    End If
                Next
                Dim diff = FieldInfos.Count - allLines.Length
                If diff <> 0 Then
                    Dim line As Int32
                    For line = (1 + allLines.Length) To (diff + allLines.Length)
                        ' set value=String.Empty for each missing line '
                        Dim q = From field In Me.FieldInfos
                                    Where field.Value.Line = line
                                    Select field
                        If q.Any Then
                            Me.FieldInfos(q.First.Key).Value = String.Empty
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                Me.Addr1 = Me.FieldInfos("Addr1").Value
                Me.Addr2 = Me.FieldInfos("Addr2").Value
                Me.Addr3 = Me.FieldInfos("Addr3").Value
                Me.City = Me.FieldInfos("City").Value
                Me.State = Me.FieldInfos("State").Value
                Me.Zip = Me.FieldInfos("Zip").Value
                Me.Country = Me.FieldInfos("Country").Value
        End Select
    End Sub

    Protected Sub BtnSwitchMode_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSwitchMode.Click
        Dim newMode As ViewMode = If(Me.Mode = ViewMode.Basic, ViewMode.Extended, ViewMode.Basic)
        Me.Mode = newMode
    End Sub

End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class FieldInfo
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Value As String
    Public Property Line As Int32
    Public Sub New(ByVal line As Int32, ByVal ID As String, ByVal Value As String)
        Me.Line = line
        Me.ID = ID
        Me.Value = Value
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: it works if all the address lines (add1,add2,add3,city,state,zip,country) are entered. let us say, if i give add1,add3,state,country then how to know exactly to place these in the respective text boxes in extended mode.

Comment: Thanks Tim.it works if all the add1, add2, add3, city, state,zip, country are given. how if i give only the add1, add3, state, country are given. how can we know that add2 is empty and add3 is placed in correct text box and so on.please help.

Comment: @Kompella: I don't understand the problem. You have 7 fields. If you switch to basic mode you have a String-Array with length 7 that you pass to the above property. The Textbox.Text will be filled correctly with NewLines after each field. If the user removes one line there will be an empty line which is  still  in the String-Array(as empty line) and the Array-Length is still 7. So there shouldn't be a problem to switch to extended mode.

Comment: @Kompella: Edited my answer. Why don't you simply pass always an Array with length 7 to the property even if not all fields are filled in extended-mode? On this way you can switch easily between both modes.

Comment: Tim, When we switch from extended to basic mode, i am doing what you said. passing the values from textboxes to an array. But i am only displaying the address lines which are not empty in the textbox (Basic mode). now, if i modify something and switch to extended. it is needed to find the correct address line and place the text. i will give you a diagramatic approach in a post after this. Thanks.

Comment: i want to upload a txt file for you illustrating my problem. if you give any mail id, i will upload that.

Comment: Edit your question, post it there and [format it as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). I thought you would add the empty fields as empty line in basic-mode, then every line would belong to one field.

Comment: yes, now i think i made you understand my problem. i am not adding the empty fields to the basic mode. ok, i will try to post as code.

Comment: @Kompella: But how do you want to detect which line belongs to the corect field if the user inserts new lines. You have to map each line with the according field.

Comment: @Kompalla: Finally created a Sample-UserControl that should do what you need.

Comment: I am sorry, the user control is working as my one. i gave add1, add2, state, country and i switch to basic mode. and again when i switch to extended, the text boxes from top to bott are filled.

Comment: @Kompalla:Ok, i see what you mean. But what you are trying to achieve is impossible and makes no sense. You shouldn't use a simple multiline Textbox for this purpose because there is no distinctive feature than the linenumber(the values can be changed/swapped by the user). But this linenumber is meaningless since you want no empty lines. In my opinion this behaviour is desirable, because the user could insert empty lines to skip empty fields(try out). My recommandation: remove every `If field.Length <> 0 Then` from my source-code and you get the best result(with empty lines in basic-mode).